# Asp.net mvc. Routing with trailing slash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to have two routes, for example:

http://localhost:1227/Product

and

http://localhost:1227/Category/

trailing slash is the only difference.

In first case I want to show information about product in other case about category. "Product" and "Category" are names of some products or categories

Is it possible to implement?

My approach:

Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("category route", "{name2}", new { controller = "test", action = "GoToView2" }, new { name2 = ".*/?" });
routes.MapRoute("product route", "{name}", new { controller = "test", action = "GoToView1"});
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Test/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GoToView1(string name)
        {
            // call to db to get some information about product
            return View((object) name);
        }

        public ActionResult GoToView2(string name2)
        {
            // call to db to get some information about category
            return View((object)name2);
        }
    }
```

Index View:

......

```
<br/>
<a href="@Url.Action("GoToView1", new { name = "Prouct"} )">Show proudct</a>
<br/>
<a href="@Url.Action("GoToView2", new { name2 = "Category" + "/"  } )">Show category</a>
```

......

But I see that only "GoToView2" is called for two link.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why would one wants to do that? in your case you have to completely different controller, namely `Product` and `Category` and two different action, and even if we could implement the same URL to call different action based on slash, it would be a code smell(bad design), in your case you can simply call `TestController/GoToView1` and `TestController/GoToView2`, if this is not the case, tell us exactly what problem you are trying to solve, maybe there would be a better approach.